# How do I loop through refs made from a v-for to then add a class depending if the radio is clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, ref

here is what my services page currently looks like:

[image]

So when you choose one of the **blue radio buttons**, it loads the **green radio buttons** which are sub options, clicking on a green sub option will show the information for that specific product/service.

As you can see when you select a categeory and then a service, it all works correct but I need to add an "active-radio-button" class to the ones that are currently selected.

Similar to a nav bar showing which page is currently active.

I've tried giving each radio button a $ref and then I loop through all the refs to see if they are checked, however it doesnt work, I can't even figure out how to print each ref to the console (although I can see them in the Vue developer console).

Here is the service page:

```
    <template>
      <div class="services">
        <div class="header services__header">
          <h1 :class="$mq">Services</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="services__services-container">
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <div
              class="services__services-container__category-selection"
              :key="`category-${index}`"
              v-for="(item, index) in this.JSON"
            >
              <!-- GENERATE CATEGORIES -->
    
              <input
                v-model="currentCategory"
                @change="UncheckRadio"
                type="radio"
                class="services__services-container__category-selection__category"
                :class="$mq"
                :value="item"
                :ref="item.name"
              />
              <label :for="item">{{ item.name }}</label>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <!-- GENERATE SERVICES -->
          <div class="services__services-container__service-selection" v-if="currentCategory != null">
            <div class="select-wrapper">
              <div
                class="services__services-container__service-selection__service"
                :key="`option-${index}`"
                :class="$mq"
                v-for="(option, index) in currentCategory.options"
              >
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  class="services__services-container__service-selection__service__wrapper"
                  :class="$mq"
                  :value="option"
                  v-model="currentService"
                  :ref="option.optionName"
                />
                <label :for="option">{{ option.optionName }}</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- GENERATE DESCRIPTIONS -->
          <div class="services__services-container__product-description" v-if="currentService != ''">
            <div class="services__services-container__product-description__description" :class="$mq">
              <div :class="$mq">
                <img :src="currentService.images" alt />
                <p>{{ currentService.description }}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import services from "@/JSON/services.json";
    export default {
      name: "Services",
      data: function() {
        return {
          JSON: [],
          currentCategory: "",
          currentService: ""
        };
      },
      created: function() {
        //TO TEST
        this.JSON = services.services;
      },
      methods: {
        UncheckRadio: function() {
          this.currentService = "";
          console.log("kek");
          for (const ref in this.refs) {
            console.log(ref.key);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
    <style lang="scss">
    @import "@/scss/variables.scss";
    @import "@/scss/button.scss";
    @import "@/scss/header.scss";
    @import "@/scss/input.scss";
    .services {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 15vh auto auto auto;
    
      &__services-container {
        //FLEX
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        //
        padding: 2rem;
    
        &__category-selection {
          //FLEX
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          flex-direction: column;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          //
          position: relative;
          padding: 1rem;
          cursor: pointer;
          & input {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 100;
            opacity: 0;
          }
          & label {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: $colour-blue;
          }
        }
    
        &__service-selection {
          &__service {
            //FLEX
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            //
            position: relative;
            padding: 1rem;
            cursor: pointer;
            & input {
              cursor: pointer;
              position: absolute;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              z-index: 100;
              opacity: 0;
            }
            & label {
              cursor: pointer;
              color: $colour-green;
            }
          }
        }
        /* For IE10 */
        select::-ms-expand {
          display: none;
        }
    
        &__product-description {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          flex-direction: column;
          @include green-gradient;
          padding: 2rem;
          border-radius: 1.5rem;
          &__description {
            & img {
              margin-bottom: 1rem;
              height: 10rem;
              width: 10rem;
              object-fit: cover;
            }
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            text-align: center;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    .select-wrapper {
      //FLEX
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      //
      border-radius: 1.5rem;
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    
    .select-icon {
      font-size: 1rem;
      color: $white;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0.5rem;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .transition {
      transition: all 0.25s linear;
    }

.active-radio-button {
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid black;
}
    </style>
```